# Passing variable from one powershell task to other powershell task with in same step in YAML

Tags: powershell, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using Azure DevOps pipeline to execute test on using TAEF from powershell, and want to share the test output from mail. Pipeline outputs following error:

Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The
request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Unexpected
character encountered while parsing value: }. Path 'email_body', line 5,
position 0.'."}}

Following is the code in my Pipeline.

```
- powershell: |
          echo "Running TAEF"
          $output = & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\TE.exe' x.dll
          $jsonOutput = $output | ConvertTo-Json

- task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: Send Email
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            $url = "xxxx"

            $headers = @{
                "Content-Type" = "application/json"
            }

            $emailMessage = @"
            {
                "to": "abc@abc.com",
                "subject": "Test",
                "email_body": $jsonOutput
            }
            "@

            Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $emailMessage
```

Couple of questions:
Can we use defined variable from powershell into another powershell task?
If not how to achieve it?

Comment: Change `"email_body": $jsonOutput` to `"email_body": "$jsonOutput"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i tried that out although not able to see any error but also i am not getting any output at "email_body", basically it seems to be null/ empty. I am assuming this means $jsonOutput is not present while execution of this command.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable assumption, yes :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen This leads to we can't use a defined variable in one PowerShell task to another powershell task just by using $var. There needs to be more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set variables in you powershell script **and use them in your subsequent tasks** and throughout your jobs. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#about-tasksetvariable)

> When you add a variable with `task.setvariable`, the following tasks can
> use the variable using macro syntax `$(myVar)`. The variable will only
> be available to tasks in the same job by default.

**Example**

```
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar;]foo"
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Next powershell task
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Write-Host "You can use macro syntax for variables: $(myVar)"'
```

**Output**

`You can use macro syntax for variables: foo`